# Can Glicko-2 accept any outcomes besides wins, losses, and draws?

Tags: game

This seems like the best place listed to ask (apologies if it's not) but I'm extremely curious: 
 Glicko and Glicko-2 are ratings algorithms designed for chess (as an improvement to the Elo rating system) to assess a player's strength at a game of skill. I've been reading about it the past couple of days and I noticed that the algorithms can only accept 3 outcomes: wins, losses, and draws. As such, the variable in the formulas that represent the match's outcome can only be a 1, 1/2, or 0. **Would it be at all possible to reverse-engineer or modify the equations to accept outcomes beyond this range** - like a "crushing" victory or loss? 
 I'm hazarding towards "no" because even if it were possible to include a "1.5" result, in turn a "-0.5" result would also have to exist and I'm imagining negative numbers would break the *HELL* out of these algorithms.

Comment: This looks a bit like math rather than software or hardware RE

Comment: You need to add some references for those who don’t know what are these things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing this answer on the Wikipedia pages about [Elo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) and [Glicko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system). When you say the variable in the formulas that represent the match's outcome *have to be* a 1, 1/2, or 0, that depends on where you see the match outcome. The expected match outcome in Elo, for instance, is computed using the [logistic curve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) which has a range between 0 and 1, so the expected outcome in that system can never be a 1.5 or a -0.5. This looks like it is also true in Glicko. Not the same formula exactly, but one which is based on the logistic curve with the output range between 0 and 1.

The Wikipedia article on Elo also points out that there are multiple ways to interpret the expected outcome.

> Thus, an expected score of 0.75 could represent a 75% chance of winning, 25% chance of losing, and 0% chance of drawing. On the other extreme it could represent a 50% chance of winning, 0% chance of losing, and 50% chance of drawing. The probability of drawing, as opposed to having a decisive result, is not specified in the Elo system.

Say there was a "crushing loss" with a value of 1.5. You would never be able to have the system predict that it would be a crushing loss with anything more than a 66% chance because that is the maximum output of the logistic curve formula.

Hope that helps.